# Как сделать при наведении курсора на картинку с текстом (которая является ссылкой) так, чтобы анимация срабатывала только на картинку?

Tags: css, transition

Пробовал текст делать ссылкой и добавлять на него фон, анимация происходит картинки вместе с текстом. Попробовал отдельно сделать два разных блока: картинку и текст, тогда не весь блок работает как ссылка.

Comment: Тут можно приложить пример кода, поищите)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```css
.link {border:1px solid red; padding: 10px; display:inline-block;}
.link img {width:128px; height:128px; transition-duration: 0.5s;}
.link span {font-size:20px; text-decoration:underline;color:blue;}

.link:hover img{transform:scale(1.1)}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">
<img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2016/08/04/806442_flower_512x512.png"/>
<br>
<span>This is link text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь блок, добавляешь в него отдельно текст и картинку. Кликабельным делаешь именно сам блок, а не отдельные его элементы.

Пример:

```
<div href="url-address">
  <img src="путь-к-картинке">
  <span>Это что? А, это текст!</span>
</div>
```